# Connection forgets its current schema and throws `SQL -204` error

Tags: java, database, spring, web-applications, connection-pooling

I'm using Spring + WebSphere + DB2 and I'm  getting the following SQL error every serveral minutes:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=USERNAME.TABLENAME, DRIVER=4.12.93
```

This is how my code looks like (simplified):

```
public class DataSourceHandler {
    @Resource( name="jdbc/db2" )
    private DataSource db2;
    private Connection conn = null;

    public Connection getConnection(DataSourceType type){
        if(conn == null) {
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            setSchema();
        }
        return conn;
    }
    private void setSchema() {
        Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        st.execute("set current schema = SCHEMA_NAME");
    }
}
```

Everytime before I execute a prepared Statement, the `DataSourceHandler` ensures that the correct schema is set.

However, I regularly get the `-204` error, indicating that the connection forgot the schema. This happens at random positions throughout the application and also for connections where I successfully performed another query right before the exception.

I'm using multiple threads which are simultaneously accessing the database. However, I ensure that each thread has it's own `DataSource` and therefore own `Connection`s.

I suspect that there are connection pooling issues but can't find out what might be the reason for it and how I can prevent the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the current schema for the connection while creating the connection itself in the resource configuration:-

url="${jdbc.url}:currentSchema=${schema.name};"